# Microsoft Bot Framework webcomponent is not working

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework

Since this midmorning (11am uk time - 18th of July) we are having an important issues trying to open a Bot inside the webcomponent offered by the Bot Framework. Is it any know issue in the Bot Framework?

When we try to open the URL associated with the webcomponent (https://webchat.botframework.com/embed/[name_of_the_bot]?s=[key]) the response is:

"The service is unavailable."

It's an intermittent issue. It fails 1 out 2 times about.

Comment: Is this still happening?

Comment: now is working fine. Is it any place to check the health of the service?

Comment: Microsoft Bot Framework is still in a preview and actively being improved upon.  Sorry, there's currently no place to check the 'health of the service'.  Please file an issue on the BotBuilder GitHub repository if you believe there is a service outage: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/

Answer (score 0):

I have talked to Microsoft folks and they have fixed that issue. You can activate bot analytics to check the bot health via dashboard.

Analytics are not available until Application Insights has been enabled and configured. Application Insights will begin collecting data as soon as it is enabled. For example, if Application Insights was enabled a week ago for a six-month-old bot, it will have collected one week of data.

**Note:Analytics requires both an Azure subscription and Application Insights resource. To access Application Insights, open the bot in the Bot Framework Portal and click Settings.**

1. Create an Application Insights resource.
2. Open the bot in the dashboard. Click Settings and scroll down to the Analytics section.
3. Enter the information to connect the bot to Application Insights.
   All fields are required.

[image: AN IMAGE!]

AppInsights Instrumentation Key

To find this value, open Application Insights and navigate to Configure > Properties.
AppInsights API key

Provide an Azure App Insights API key. Learn how to generate a new API key. Only Read permission is required.
AppInsights Application ID

To find this value, open Application Insights and navigate to Configure > API Access.